# CQL query to get count of elements in LIST DATATYPE of CassandraDB?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, cql, cqlsh

I have a column in my table which has list datatype. I want to get count of  items in the list using **CQL**
I tried but I am unable to find the correct query . Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there isn't a standard way in Cassandra to accomplish this.  The easiest way would be to `SELECT` the list from the table and pull a count of its items on the application side.

That being said, there *is* a way to accomplish this by building a **user defined function** (UDF).  First of all, UDFs are disabled by default with Cassandra, to prevent execution of malicious code by users of a cluster.  If you're ok with enabling them, you'll find that option in the `cassandra.yaml` file.  It's a simple boolean, so you'll want to set it to `true`:

```
enable_user_defined_functions: true
```

Of course, you'll have to stop/restart the cluster for this change to take effect.

Next, you can create a UDF to return an integer representing the size of the list, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countlist (input List<text>)
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS int
    LANGUAGE java AS 'return input.size();';
```

Essentially what this does, is the `List<text>` Cassandra type gets mapped to a `java.util.List<String>` Java type.  From there, it simply invokes the `size()` method on the list.

Now, I can use that `countlist` function with CQL.  So let's say I have a table to keep track of parents' children:

```
CREATE TABLE kids (
    parent text PRIMARY KEY,
    children list<text>);
```

For me, I can query it like this:

```
SELECT parent,countlist(children) FROM kids WHERE parent='Aaron';

 parent | stackoverflow.countlist(children)
--------+-----------------------------------
  Aaron |                                 4

(1 rows)
```